# Ubuntu 14.04 printer driver for Canon E460

Tags: printing, canon

I am looking for Canon printer driver for model E460. I am unable to find an updated driver for this model.

Answer (score 0):

There's a driver from Canon, downloadable on their website ( http://support-my.canon-asia.com/contents/MY/EN/0100626502.html )

Comment: that doesn't seem to be for this particular printer....

Comment: How about the linux driver for canon pixma e464? https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/inkjet/other_pixma/pixma_e464.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)

edit - welp, that seems to be the same driver... did you try it?